# I have problem in transferring data from activity to another activity

Tags: java, android

```
public class Memo extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHandler dbh;
Notes items;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_memo);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    try{
        dbh = new DBHandler(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   display();
}

public void display( ){              //method to display all items in the database
    List<Notes> books_list = dbh.getNotes();             ////here i get the list fromm the database
    ///// i used a custom adapter because i needed it
    final myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, books_list);          ///creating adapter from 
myadapter to link it with  the list
    ListView _note_ = findViewById(R.id.list_txt);
    _note_.setAdapter(adapter);

    _note_.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {     
            items = (Notes) adapter.getItem(position);
            String Note_content = items.getNote();
            String title = items.getTitle();
            String Date = items.getDate();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,Note_content.class);
            i.putExtra("Note ", Note_content);
            i.putExtra("title", title);
            i.putExtra("Date", Date);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

i have a problem when I try to to get data( only Note) from this activity to another activity, other values(Date and Title) are working, I tried to use toString method in Notes class but it gives null for note

```
public class Note_content extends AppCompatActivity {
Notes item;
TextView txt_note ,txt_date , txt_title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_content);
    txt_title = findViewById(R.id.txt_ntitle);
    txt_note = findViewById(R.id.txt_Nnote);
    txt_date = findViewById(R.id.txt_Ndate);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String note = i.getStringExtra("Note");
    String title = i.getStringExtra("title");
    String date = i.getStringExtra("Date");
     item = new Notes(title,note,date);

    txt_note.setText(item.getNote());
    //txt_note.setText(note)
    txt_date.setText(date);
    txt_title.setText(title);
}
```

this is the second  activit, it is not giving any errors but null instead of the note
and this Notes class

```
 public class Notes {
    private  int id;
    private String title;
    private String note ;
    private String date;

    public Notes() {
    }

    public Notes(String title, String note, String date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.note = note;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.note+"\n"+title+"\n"+date;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the `Notes` class?

Comment: Can you confirm, that the variable Note_content is not null when you put it inside your intent (Log it)?

Comment: @Sz-NikaJanos yes this was the problem. I was sure about the code but this space was the error .Thank you

Comment: @muaazDeyab please mark my comment so it people know what was the issue as this question gets new posts. 

Thank you! have an amazing day. If you still need help. reach out.

Answer (score 0):

i.putExtra("Note ", Note_content);
In the above code line, "Note " has an extra space at the end.

Comment: I already mentioned this in the comments, this was the issue